# Taking picture from camera in android fragment is not working

Tags: android, camera, fragment

I am able to take picture from gallery but found problem in capture from camera in fragment.
After picture taken onActivityResult is some times called and when called it gives some exception file not found.

my code is

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
if(flag==0){
    try{                   
       String URI = getImageURI();
       String imageName = URI.substring(URI.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
       FileInputStream fis = mContext.openFileInput(imageName);
       Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.preRotate(90);
       photo = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo , 0, 0, photo.getWidth(),    photo.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
            Log.e("Error - ",e.getMessage());
    }
   }
 }

 public void takePictureFromCamera(){
              File style = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"style");
      if(!style.exists()){style.mkdir();}
        String d = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";
        File f = new File(style, d+"style.jpg");
        absPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        savePref(absPath);
        cameraImagePath = Uri.fromFile(f);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraImagePath);
        }
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
  }
```

Comment: 1. For "file now found error"On which device you are testing, i.e. Nexus doesn't supports Memory card so can not get with **getExternalStorageDirectory** method or second reason is you did not added write permission in manifest, 2. for **onActivtyResult not getting called** reason is because it calls it's super activity's onActivityResult so you may need to call child fragment's method from there.

Comment: Thannks for your answer,i am testing it on samsung galaxy s4 and added permission in manifest.And which method i have to call from onActivityResult as you mention that call child fragment method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the steps how I am handling onActivityResult method issue.

I have One MainActivity and one child Fragment.
now my Fragment's onActivityResult is not getting called, instead it calls MainActivity's (super) onActivityResult.
So below is the sample code snip to get it work

1. This "onActivityResult" i have overridden in my main activity and from here I am calling child fragment's onActivityResult method if needed.

   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

   ```
   {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch (requestCode) 
         {
       case Session.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_CODE:
       {
           Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
           fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       }

           break;

       default:
           break;
       }       
   }
   ```

"content_frame" is Frame layout inside my Main Activity's XML file

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I start, my profile fragment this way in MainActivity class

```
ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
   Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
   args2.putInt(ActivityFeedFragment.ARG_NAVIGATIN_LIST_NUMBER, position);
   args2.putString(Utils.serfrmuserid, AssetPref.getString(Utils.User_ID, null));
   fragment.setArguments(args2);

   FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Adding onActivityResult in my Activity and  After modication in my code it work for me.thanks you save my life.